# workflow to make an overleaf article arXiv-compliant

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

On Overleaf I'm preparing an article for submission to arXiv.  I've modeled it on a recently submitted similar [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09892).  ArXiv's TeX log reports some errors.  I google the errors, guess at a fix, and then:

- download the source files from overleaf to my PC, as a .zip
- upload them from my PC to arxiv.org/submit/1234567
  (as an entire .zip, instead of mouseclicking for ages to upload each individual file)
- reprocess on arXiv, and usually discover that I guessed wrong.

**Can I shorten this cycle?**
Configure Overleaf to use arXiv's TeX Live 2016?
Edit files in place on arXiv?
Duplicate arXiv's toolchain on my own (Ubuntu) PC?
Push the .zip from Overleaf to arXiv, or pull it from arXiv?
Something else?

Overleaf's own "submit" button (to arXiv) leads to the steps: download zip, download pdf, submit to arXiv.  But it doesn't actually send any files to arXiv, and it produces no error log, so what purpose could it have?

Comment: The third option (duplicate arXiv's toolchain on your pc) seems the only one that is possible. Luckily that is relatively easy, see https://www.tug.org/historic/.

Comment: OK, I'm trying ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) If you'd like a particular project on Overleaf to compile on TeX Live 2016, contact us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL. We can manually set the project to use our TeX Live 2016 image, which will be closer to arXiv's TeX Live 2016. We can't guarantee an exact match of all package versions, but it should behave much more similar to arXiv.

Comment: The reason for the submit flow is that we don't have a direct submission agreement with arXiv (this would require some coordination between parties). So the arXiv submit flow in Overleaf is really just a convenient way to download all the files that are needed by arXiv's own submission process.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense.  I've made the request, Paul.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

Note that both arXiv and Overleaf now use TeX Live 2020 with quite similar configurations. So it should be -- in most cases -- enough to hit Submit -> arXiv in Overleaf, this will generate a ZIP file that should be arXiv-ready.