# What is the Meaning of 'LaTeX Document' in the Context of Journal Submission?

Tags: pdf, overleaf, document

I am going to submit solutions to the School Science and Mathematics Association journal. They require solutions to be uploaded in both LaTeX document and PDF formats. I have written the solution in LaTeX code and generated a PDF, but I am unsure about what exactly is meant by 'LaTeX document.'

Can someone help me to upload the latex file

Comment: They mean the source files, i.e. everything necessary for them to generate the document: `.tex` file(s), pictures, but possibly also `.bib` and `.bst` and so on.

Comment: @campa i did not understand what you want to say because i am totally new in latex i have pdf solution that i made in overleaf

Comment: In overleaf you also have a `.tex` file, that is where your code is storred. The journal want that as well, If you use bibtex or biblatex for your refecences then they also need that. You can download your entire projecty from overleaf as a ZIP, all the sources will be in that ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I’ve got the Tex file,I'm really happy now.

Comment: Related: [How to download an Overleaf template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229205/277964)

Comment: And I you need an archive with `bbl`-file, see e.g., [workflow to make an overleaf article arXiv-compliant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506402/277964).